# Skip http_basic_authentication_with for a specific route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In rails, I have a base controller that defines `http_basic_authentication_with` and I would like to have a specific route skip that in a subclass. This would be similar to how I can specify a controller `skip_before_filter`. Is this possible?

My base controller looks something like this:

```
class BaseController < ApplicationController
  http_basic_authenticate_with name: "name", password: "password"
end
```

And I have a controller that inherits from that:

```
class HomeController < BaseController
   def index
   end

   def no_auth
   end
 end
```

I would like it so that "index" requires basic auth, but "no_auth" does not.

Thanks!

Comment: do you want to just show a little code?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think code would be helpful, but just in case, I added some.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it.

```
class BaseController < ApplicationController
  http_basic_authenticate_with name: "name", password: "password"
end
```

Let's replace `http_basic_authenticate_with` by our own class method. Let's call it `auth_setup`.

```
class BaseController < ApplicationController
  auth_setup

  def self.auth_setup
    http_basic_authenticate_with name: "name", password: "password"
  end
end
```

Since we don't want to call it in every subclass, we can extract just the parameters to other method. Let's call it auth_params.

```
class BaseController < ApplicationController
  auth_setup

  def self.auth_setup
    http_basic_authenticate_with auth_params
  end

  def self.auth_params
    { name: 'name', password: 'password' }
  end
end
```

From now on, we can use this method to modify auth parameters in our subclasses. For example:

```
class HomeController < BaseController    
  def index
  end

  def no_auth
  end

  def self.auth_params
    (super).merge(except: :index)
  end
end
```

However, method calls in Ruby class definitions aren't inherited (it's easy to forget *with Rails style of things*). Depending on implementation of `http_basic_authenticate_with` you're going to need another fix - `inherited` callback.

```
class BaseController < ApplicationController
  auth_setup

  def self.auth_setup
    http_basic_authenticate_with auth_params
  end

  def self.auth_params
   { name: 'name', password: 'password' }
  end

  def self.inherited(subclass)
    subclass.auth_setup
  end
end
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work for me because I am trying to do an "except" for a route that is in a subclass. (The http_basic_authenticate_with is defined in separate controller than where I want to add the "except")

Comment: I don't want to redefine the basic auth. That will mean multiple places to maintain the basic auth username and password.

Comment: I've just came up with idea. One sec.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :auth

  def auth
    pass = ENV['AUTH'].split ':'
    http_basic_authenticate_or_request_with name: pass[0], password: pass[1]
  end
```

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController

  skip_before_action :auth, only: [:ping]
```